# How do I weight distances in KNNRegression when company in training set is the same as the one we are predicting for?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, data-modeling, knn

I have duplicates in my training set for the same company but for different years which is fine. When I'm predicting using KNN I don't want the previous years values to be used as the nearest neighbours of the company I'm predicting for. Is there a way I can weight the rows from that company in the training set so that they aren't used as the nearest neighbour?

Example

| id | year | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 77 | 2018 | 10 | 100 |
| 77 | 2019 | 12 | 102 |
| 77 | 2020 | 16 | 150 |
| 89 | 2019 | 3 | 97 |
| 44 | 2021 | 7 | 88 |
| 55 | 2022 | 19 | 78 |

In the above example if I was predicting for id 77 year 2021 I wouldn't want to use the other values from id 77 in the training set to predict y. The reason for this is that historical values wont be available on our unseen data so it needs to be taken out when training.

Results:

```
KNeighborsRegressor MAE mean score: 146334.58
KNeighborsRegressor r2 mean score: 0.91
```

I'm getting very good results but think this is due to the model using its own previous records to predict future records and so is performing very well.